# Definition of the canonical basis of F^n

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Can someone define for me in an intuitive way the canonical basis?

My textbook defines it like this:
[image]

But I don't really understand what it means

Thanks

Comment: If you think of the 3d space where we've living, you'll realize how intuitive your canonical basis is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider your introduction to $\mathbb R^3$

Any vector can be written $a\mathbf i + b\mathbf j + c\mathbf k$

And we call $\mathbf i,\mathbf j, \mathbf k$ principle component vectors.

You could also write this vector as $(a,b,c)$

Which means that $\mathbf i = (1,0,0), \mathbf j = (0,1,0), \mathbf k = (0,0,1)$

$\mathbf i,\mathbf j, \mathbf k$ form a basis for $\mathbb R^3$  However, they are not the only basis.  Any set of independent vectors can from a basis.

$\mathbf i,\mathbf j, \mathbf k$ are the most simple and direct way.  We call this the canonical basis.